# Build form control from array - Angular 4

Tags: angular

i have an angular4 form which is built using form builder. The code is as follows.

```js
initializeFromControls() {
    let obj = {
      firstname: new FormControl('', ),
      lastname: new FormControl('', ),
      email: new FormControl('',
              [Validators.required,
              Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]),
      status: new FormControl('', ),
      role_id: new FormControl('')         
    }
    this.userFrm = this.formBuilder.group(obj);
  }
```

Now i have another field named account_ids which is an array. The account ids are fetched from the getAccounts api call.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeFromControls();
    this.getAccounts();
  }
```

For each account i need to show a checkbox and account name. The selected accounts are to be sent in the format 
`account_ids: [1,2,3]`

How to achieve this using FormBuilder.

Comment: Have you taken a look into `FormArray` ?

Comment: instead of creating new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782076/pre-populate-formarray-on-edit-page-angular4) you should edit this one

Answer (score 0):

in initialization of `obj` add:

```
let obj = {
  ...
  accounts: this.formBuilder.array([])
  ...
}
```

then, after you'll get your `account_ids`, write:

```
account_ids.forEach(acc_id => {
  this.userFrm.get('accounts').push(
    FormControl(acc_id)
  )
}
```

but remember that account "1" will be on position 0 in `this.userFrm.get('accounts')` in this case.