# Pre populate formArray on edit page - Angular4

Tags: angular

i have an angular4 form which is built using form builder. The code is as follows.

```js
initializeFromControls() {
    let obj = {
      firstname: new FormControl('', ),
      lastname: new FormControl('', ),
      email: new FormControl('',
              [Validators.required,
              Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]),
      status: new FormControl('', ),
      role_id: new FormControl(''),
      account_ids: this.formBuilder.array([])         
    }
    this.userFrm = this.formBuilder.group(obj);
  }
```

Now i have another field named account_ids which is an array. The account ids are fetched from the getAccounts api call.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeFromControls();
    this.getAccounts();
  }
```

Selected Account ids are send to backend using the following code.

```
onChange(account_id:string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const accountIdArray = <FormArray>this.userFrm.controls.account_ids;

    if(isChecked) {
      accountIdArray.push(new FormControl(account_id));
    } else {
      let index = accountIdArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == account_id)
      accountIdArray.removeAt(index);
    }

    console.log(this.userFrm.getRawValue());
  }
```

**Now I need to pre-populate account ids (formArray) on edit page.**

The template is as follows.

```
<div *ngFor="let account of accounts">
              <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(account.id, $event.target.checked)">{{account.id}}  {{account.acc_name}}<br>
            </div>
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: maybe you can read this
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

for prepopulate the input there is different ways depending the data model you choose
for example: [(ngModel)],  [value] or formControlName attributes

Answer (score 2):

Your initialization is fine.
Here how I did in my case where on the edit page I had to prepopulate FormArray:

```
items: FormArray;

//response from server
response['data'].map((item, index) => {

    const tmpDict = {};
    tmpDict['firstname'] = new FormControl(item.firstname);
    tmpDict['lastname'] = new FormControl(item.lastname);
    tmpDict['email'] = new FormControl(item.email);

   this.items = this.userFrm.get('items') as FormArray;
   this.items.push(new FormGroup(tmpDict));
})
```